# Cannot run extension commands in WinDBG

Tags: windows, windbg, debug-symbols, wdk

(Sorry for the analogous question I posted, I've modified it.)
I'm trying to debug an excutable PE file on windows XP to see how PDE and PTE works in a real system. I've learned that windbg have some commands to see the details. It seems that !pte would be able to see the corresponding PDE and PTE of a virtual address. But I come across

`0:000> !pte
No export pte found`

I did some google work and find that it is an [extension command](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2009/11/27/common-windbg-commands-reference/), but I don't see any description on how to enable these extensions. It seems that everybody is using it directly except me.

I wonder what I have missed but I couldn't figure out. Could anyone please give me some advice?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean it is better to debug from another computer?

Comment: No. It means that `!pte` is probably irrelevant to the problem you're trying to solve. Your question is analogous to asking "I'm performing user mode-debugging but the [`!idt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563219(v=vs.85).aspx) command to display interrupts doesn't work! Should I use two computers?" No. This command had nothing to do with user-mode debugging.

Comment: Why do you think the `!pte` would be helpful? What other commands did you use so far? What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you debug an executable? Does it crash? WinDbg has hundreds of commands. Why did you choose this one for debugging?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I'm trying to debug an excutable PE file on windows XP to see how PDE and PTE works in a real system. I've modified the answer

Comment: then you should do kernel debugging not user mode debugging if all you are interested is in viewing the pde pte of a virtual address you can use local kernel debugging in the same machine take a look at my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are using **xp** `Local Kernel Debugging` support is available without having to edit boot configuration and rebooting

if you are on an operating system higher that xp you need to edit the boot configuration of the os with /debug on switch and reboot for local kernel debugging support

`bcdedit /debug on and reboot` only then `windbg -kl` will work on os greater than **XP**

```
if you don't want to edit your boot configuration download livekd     
from sysinternals and use it instead for local kernel debugging
```

open windbg with this command-line

```
windbg -kl
```

this will open windbg with the prompt `lkd>` instead of the `0:000>`

now you can use the `!pte` command

substitute **explorer.exe** with the name of the binary that is running which you want to examine  (be aware this is not usermode you are looking at the kernel mode part of your binary)
**in the example below i am using livekd in windows 7 x86 32 bit physical machine**

```
C:\>livekd    
LiveKd v5.40 - Execute kd/windbg on a live system
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
Copyright (C) 2000-2015 Mark Russinovich and Ken Johnson

Launching C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\kd.exe:

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17298 X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

kd> !process 0 0 explorer.exe

PROCESS 864b2638  SessionId: 1  Cid: 05f8    Peb: 7ffde000  ParentCid: 05e4
    DirBase: 7e28c2c0  ObjectTable: 964ccad8  HandleCount: 1062.
    Image: explorer.exe

kd> .process /p /r 864b2638
Implicit process is now 864b2638
Loading User Symbols

kd> !pte explorer
                    VA 00400000
PDE at C0600010            PTE at C0002000
contains 000000000FFB2867  contains 80000000103F7025
pfn ffb2      ---DA--UWEV  pfn 103f7     ----A--UR-V

kd> $$ page table entry contains 103f7025
kd> dc c0002000 l1
c0002000  103f7025                             %p?.
kd> $$ the top 5 bytes are page frame nos lets see if the physical page contains MZ
kd> !dc 103f7000 l1
#103f7000 00905a4d MZ.......L`...ac
kd>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very useful and practical. I'll learn to use livevd.

Comment: I have tested it these days, but it turns out that PAE is enabled in my machine, so `!pte` won't work correctly due to the existence of PDPE(to find this fact has costed much time). The `!vtop` command seems to be more feasible to see how a virtual address is translated into a physical address. Thanks for you help again.

Answer (score 0):

You are debugging an executable. This means you're debugging in *user mode*. Looking at an application in user mode, you'll see *virtual memory* only. The debugger will present you the same view as the application/executable has.

Virtual memory is provided to application in different ways. It could be physical memory, page file content or even nothing (for reserved memory).

Whatever it is in reality, this is hidden from the application. That's what the kernel does for you. To see how it does that, you need to use *kernel debugging*. The debugger will then let you see what the OS sees internally and allow the use of kernel related commands like `!pte` (and many more).

PTE (page table entry) and PDE (page directory entry) are exactly the "objects" the kernel uses to perform the mapping between virtual memory and physical memory.

To analyze that, you probably want to perform kernel debugging and user mode debugging at the same time, to verify that the results you get on kernel side really match the results you get on user mode side.

Since it seems you're a novice on this topic, I'd suggest doing that in a virtual machine or on a dedicated PC. Don't use a PC which has important data. In kernel mode, you can potentially cause blue screens and lose all unsaved work.

There are articles from the NT debugging blog like [Understanding !pte - Part 1 - Let's get physical](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2010/02/05/understanding-pte-part-1-lets-get-physical/) which get you started, followed by [Part 2 - Flags and Large Pages](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2010/04/14/understanding-pte-part2-flags-and-large-pages/) and [Part 3 - Non-PAE and X64](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ntdebugging/2010/06/22/part-3-understanding-pte-non-pae-and-x64/).

Comment: Kernel debugging isn't *that* dangerous. Sure, you can crash your machine, but really destroying it and corrupting persistent data requires some effort. In any case, to play around with `!pte` using `livekd` (as blabb proposed) is not only more than enough, but also easier, more user-friendly and faster.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I'm a novice on it. I'll try to understand the blogs.

Comment: @conio: yes, that's why we have blue screens: to protect you from losing more than the contents of RAM. But even losing RAM contents may hurt sometimes. I rephrased that.